# Shifting backButtonImage horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

What I need,

[image]

What I get, on adding backButtonImage,

[image]

I want to shift the backButtonImage horizontally? No answers on here seem to work for me.

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

**EDIT**

I am just setting `back image` and `back mask` in storyboard, here it is (`nav_back`)

[image]

Comment: you use a custom bar button?

Comment: just make you button size smaller slightly and it should be fine, if you're using custom images, like i believe you are, if you just make it a little wider and add some spacing then it should work like a dream :)

Comment: @PhuDuy I just added my image in storyboard. Its default one.

Comment: @Konsy Yes, that would be last option for me, to use design hack and add some empty space at start of my image.

Comment: i think you should use a custom bar button from UIButton and set `contentHorizontalAlignment` of UIButton to right

Comment: Please add some storyboard screenshot of view hierarchy and the code (if you are using any).

Comment: @Nishant Just setting `nav_back` in UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `UIBarButtonItem` Size Inspector in storyboard.

[image]

You should be able to shift image to the right by X points by setting image left inset to X and right inset to -X. This worked with bar button item with custom image but not sure if it will with default back button

Comment: Its not working, in my case its not `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem`, its `backBarButtonItem` whose property is not visible in storyboard & even adding it programmatically doesn't reflect any cange.

Comment: @RoNiT To make this work with `backBarButtonItem` you have to subclass  `UIBarButtonItem`, set custom image on it and then use your subclassed button